# Error Connecting R with Twitter Microsoft API

Tags: r, twitter, sentiment-analysis, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to run a sentiment and text analytics on RStudio and using the Microsoft Cognitive API.

I am able to connect to twitter using the requisite authentication but when i execute the code I get the error as: **Request body format is wrong. Make sure the json request is serialized correctly and there are no null members.**

The code used is

```
result_modi =POST("https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0/sentiment",
                    body = request_body_json_modi,
                    add_headers(.headers = c("Content- Type"="application/json","Ocp-Apim-Subscription-  Key"="bc8c8427fd74412ea51967373e418681")))
```

Comment: What does `request_body_json_modi` look like?  You can find the expected schema [here](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/TextAnalytics.V2.0/operations/56f30ceeeda5650db055a3c9)

Comment: `request_body_json_modi = toJSON(list(documents = request_body_modi))` and

Comment: `request_body_json_modi = toJSON(list(documents = request_body_modi))` and  `request_body_modi = modi_df[c(2,3,1)]`